# What is a replacement for Syntax Annotations?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want something instead of `SyntaxAnnotations` to set some data to `SyntaxNode` that I visit in a `SyntaxRewriter` for reuse later.

`SyntaxAnnotations` aren't available for example :

- after rerun my application
- after reopen solution with roslyn api

I don't know what can I use? I can use for example `comments` but is there a better way?

```
public override SyntaxNode VisitMethodDeclarationSyntax (MethodDeclarationSyntax m)
{
     SyntaxAnnotation a=new SyntaxAnnotation("kind","data");
    m=m.WithAdditionalAnnotations(a);
    return m;
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @mohsen If I understand what you want, comments are the only way that I can think of. The syntax tree annotations are not saved between runs.